# SQL select from table with alias (Oracle9i)

Tags: sql, oracle9i

According to Oracle documentation for statement [`SELECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/select.html) it should be possible to alias table names with aliases without or with keyword `AS`. However, aliasing tables with keyword `AS` leads to error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

For example, the following statement fails with the above error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE AS A;
```

Once keyword `AS` is removed it executes as expected.

Could anyone please comment on this. Is there a way to make the application of `AS` for table aliasing work?

P.S. I'm using a code generation utility that translate some Java code into SQL statements at runtime. This utility enforces the use of aliases with `AS`.

Comment: when i have been working with oracle DB#, i also noticed that it doesn't accept the AS identifier.

Comment: AFAIK table aliases in Oracle never accepted AS and still don't (I haven't used Oracle 12c though). I haven't seen AS for table aliases mentioned in their docs either. But I would like it to be an option. As it is no option now, I see no way to make table aliases with AS work in Oracle.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I was afraid that it would be the case (: Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you quote it it works `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual) "AS"`

Comment: @Serpiton In your case "AS" is used as an alias, but not as a keyword. Try `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 FROM dual) AS A`.

Comment: @01es yes, you're right `AS` is accepted as a keyword for column but not for table, and I should stop to try to multitask :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not accept AS for table aliases and I see no way to make it work.

Can't you do anything in Java? AS for column aliases is optional in Oracle, so you could look for all " AS " in the generated string and remove them (thus removing AS for column aliases as well as for table aliases). Is this an option?